# Opening document in client preview pane crashes Lotus Notes. Anyone seen this?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

The problem I am about to describe has been going on since we upgraded from 8.5.2 to 8.5.3.

We have a simple required reading program that routes documents to be read and has a button that allows folks to indicate that they read it. On occasion, these readings are connect to our training records database to record that someone read some training material.  That training database is an Oracle system and is updated by an Oracle procedure that is called (using LotusScript) when they press the button that they have read the document.

I have a development computer as well as a test computer.  The test computer is usually loaded with our company standard load that has been tested on all of the various types of computers we purchase.  Anyway, last year I upgraded my development computer to 8.5.3 while leaving my test computer on 8.5.2 (have since upgrade it as well).

After I upgraded my dev computer to 8.5.3, I noticed that whenever I received an error from the Notes application that there was an issue with the Oracle Procedure call, my Notes session would crash when I tried to open that email or preview it in the preview pane.  I tried opening it in the web client and had no problems.  I tried opening it with my test computer (running 8.5.2) and experienced no problems.  We have been short handed here for some time, so the priority was not very high on solving this problem.  However, now the problem has spread.  Presently, whenever a new document is created and routed, it may or may not cause the person's Notes Session to crash when they try to open the document.

I don't profess to know the inner workings of Notes and what the differences between 8.5.2 and 8.5.3 could be that might cause this.  Has anyone seen this?

Thanks,

MJ

Comment: You're talking about reasonably current versions of Notes, so I'm going to jump to the (maybe incorrect) conclusion that you have a current IBM support contract.  You're describing an intermittent reproducible crash behavior, which could be some kind of resource leak in your application, but it didn't happen prior to upgrading so it feels like a client bug.  Anyhow, there's no hint of a specific programming problem in your question, so it seems to me that you should be either calling IBM support -- or at least delving into the NSD file and the code for details yourself before posting here.

Comment: If it is code related then the following wiki article will help track down where it is happening. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Mapping__agent_code_to_NSD_crash_stack_on_Windows

Answer (score 0):

Software crashes (and other software defects) with Lotus Notes should be reported to IBM by opening a PMR on this site:
http://www.ibm.com/software/lotus/support

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know, if it is the same problem as happend in out application BUT:

We figured out, that using PNG images will crach the notes client (and the domino server). This bug happend in some versions of domino (and notes).

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO48673